# Python Geopandas to_postgis AttributeError: 'GeometryDtype' object has no attribute 'base'

Tags: python, dataframe, postgis, geopandas

I'm currently trying to read a shape file into a geopandas dataframe. Once in, I am then trying to write the dataframe to a postgres database with postgis this way:

```
df.postgis.to_postgis(con=eng, table_name=fl_nm, geometry='Polygon', if_exists='append', chunksize=20000, method='multi')
```

But when I do so, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'GeometryDtype' object has no attribute 'base'

Is there something that I'm forgetting to check before writing to a database? I'm still pretty new to working with geopandas and shape files.

Comment: I think it's `df.to_postgis`, not `df.postgis.to_postgis` (https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=postgis#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis)

Comment: I've got the same error. Did you find the source of the error?